# Why does my loop counter have an unexpected value after the loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

I have some code like:

```
num_grades = 0
for num_grades in range(8):
    grade = int(input("Enter grade " + str(num_grades + 1) + ": "))
    # additional logic to check the grade and categorize it
print("Total number of grades:", num_grades)
# additional code to output more results
```

When I try this code, I find that the displayed result for `num_grades` is `7`, rather than `8` like I expect. Why is this? What is wrong with the code, and how can I fix it? I tried adding a while loop to the code, but I was unable to fix the problem this way.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, where the code says `for num_grades in range(8):`, **exactly** what do you think this means, **step by step**? What do you think will be the value of `num_grades` the first time the loop runs? The second time? The last? Why? How many times do you think the loop will run? Why? Now, **try to [check](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)** these expectations, for example, by `print`ing the value inside the loop. Do you see an issue? Do you now understand why `num_grades` has an unexpected value *after* the loop?

Comment: Aside from that: please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. I [edit]ed the question to [remove conversational language](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343721/), **ask a clear question directly**, use tags appropriately (use them to describe **the question**, not everything that you tried) and show a [mre] (by removing the part of the code that was working and not apparently related to the problem you describe). Please carefully study the result, in order to understand best how to ask questions here.

Comment: (As a further hint: note carefully the line of code `grade = int(input("Enter grade " + str(num_grades + 1) + ": "))`. Notice how it was necessary to use `+ 1` in order to get the right value for the output? Does this **change** `num_grades`, or does it simply compute a new value? What, according to your understanding, actually causes `num_grades` to change, in the code?)

Comment: Right.  This is not C or C++.  `for num_grades in range(8):` has the same effect as `for num_grades in (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7):`.

Answer (score 1):

The last value `num_grades` gets assigned is 7 because of the range, the `num_grades + 1` has no effect on the final value of `num_grades`

You need to either change the way `num_grades` changes throughout the flow of the code, or simply add a 1 to the final result.

Answer (score 1):

In python the variable(s) that you use in for loop keep last state after the loop, `for num_grades in range(8):` will goes from 0 to 7 so after the loop `num_grads` will be 7

Answer (score 0):

I would add an if-statement in the loop checking the index.

```
num_grades = 0
for num_grades in range(9):
    if num_grades == 0:
        continue
    grade = int(input("Enter grade " + str(num_grades) + ": "))
    # additional logic to check the grade and categorize it
print("Total number of grades:", num_grades)
```

I always use if-statements within loops to negate certain indexes. If you're unaware, the `continue` keyword in a loop resets the loop and increases the loop variable by 1, without doing anything else past it. Since a loop starts at 0, then the code sees that, and skips it. Then, you can have it print `num_grades` and it'll just output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Comment: Or `for num_grades in range(1, 9):` and remove `if num_grades == 0: continue`.